# Aligning social icons to center in footer

Tags: css

I am trying to put the social icons to center, but without any result. Someone who knows what I can do to make them in center? https://postwork.se - I am talking about the social icons in the footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way it to add this style to the `p` enclosing them.

First add a class to the `p`, like this:

```
<p class="social-icons-footer">
```

Then add the style in your css file:

```
.social-icons-footer {
width: 250px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I've added
.p {
width: 250px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

- but they are still not in center... :(

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize

```css
/* style for div parent of links */
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

To do that  wrap all the links in div and apply this to it. See screenshot below.
But in order for it to work properly wrap all images with

```
<a>
```

tag. 
Notice that flexbox is not yet supported in older browsers in case you require to support them.
[screenshot of display: flex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck8lB.png)